# Highcharts - How to draw Confidence Intervals

Tags: javascript, graph, highcharts, intervals

i wonder if it's possible to draw confidence intervals like in this graph:

[image]
<sub>(source: [tonarchiv.ch](http://tonarchiv.ch/dl/stack/indication.png))</sub>

I.e. an interval for each sample and a point or small line in the "middle".

X-axis should just be a number (number of rating).

Comment: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/combo-multi-axes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Columnrange** is the answer! See: http://jsfiddle.net/dmN3N/18/

```
    series: [{
        type: 'columnrange',
        data: [
              [-0.547571175, 0.401498266],
              [-0.960011899, 0.444655955],
               ...
              ]
    }, {
        type: 'scatter',
        data: [-0.073036455, -0.257677972,
                0.100955985, 0.106734365,
               -0.12219027, -0.060577832
              ]
    }]
```

If required, the dashes at each end of a column (see sample pic) could be generated with other (wider than tall) column ranges...

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example rantanplan's suggestion of using columnranges for the dashes at the top and bottom of each bar:

[image: Confidence intervals in Highcharts]

The horizontal lines are created using 'columns' which are 15 pixels wide and 2 pixels tall, positioned at both ends of the data range. For example, here are the lines at the top of each bar:

```
type: 'columnrange',
pointWidth: 15,
minPointLength: 2,
data: [
    [0.40, 0.40],
    [0.30, 0.30]
]
```

Another series creates the lines at the bottom, and a third additional series (scatter) creates the diamond marker in the middle.

https://jsfiddle.net/ecjohbg1/4/

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use plotBands: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.plotBands

Comment: Sorry, the graph sample was misleading. I swapped it now. It's about the displaying type of the y-axis. Some kind of error bar around the y-value.

Comment: But it looks like as negative mark only, anyway so you would like to control tick positions or add additional line in yAxis labels, because I feel a little bit confused.

Comment: Well, seems hard to explain... It just should look exactly like the sample graph in the end. Y-values are not single points but an interval. Is there a way to display intervals as lines, with a dash on each end and one in the middle?

Answer (score 0):

There is now a series type called 'errorbar' which fits this use case perfectly. While the other solutions glue together three different series for the intervals, the errorbar series does it all with one. A separate series is still needed for the mean.

Here is an example
https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/error-bar-series

Here is the API reference https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.errorbar